# Puppeteer iterate div and then from result, iterate child element

Tags: javascript, arrays, puppeteer

I want to return an object from the HTML as below:

HTML

```
<div id="collection">
  <div class="div">
    <h1 class="title">Title 1</h1>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>list item 1</li>
      <li>list item 2</li>
      <li>list item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <h1 class="title">Title 2</h1>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>list item 1a</li>
      <li>list item 2a</li>
      <li>list item 3a</li>
      <li>list item 4a</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <h1 class="title">Title 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Required result:

```
{
  title: "Title 1",
  list:{
    item: "list item 1",
    item: "list item 2",
    item: "list item 3"
  }
},
{
  title: "Title 2",
  list:{
    item: "list item 1a",
    item: "list item 2a",
    item: "list item 3a",
    item: "list item 4a"
  }
},
{
  title: "Title 3",
  list:{}
}
```

So far I have:

```
const result = await page.$$eval('div.div, (divs) => divs.map((div) => {
   return {
      title: div.querySelector('.title').innerText,
   }
}));
console.log(result)
```

I am unsure on how I can use page.$$eval to then iterate another element; in this case the ul.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This part does not make sense: list: {item: '...', item: '...', ...}, because you are using the same object name to name different things

Comment: Apologies, it was supposed to read:
```
{
  title: "Title 1",
  list:{
    "item_a": "list item 1",
    "item_b": "list item 2",
    "item_c": "list item 3"
  }
},
{
  title: "Title 2",
  list:{
    "item_a": "list item 1a",
    "item_b": "list item 2a",
    "item_c": "list item 3a",
    "item_d": "list item 4a"
  }
},
{
  title: "Title 3",
  list:{}
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense: title: "Title 1",
  list:{
    item: "list item 1",
    item: "list item 2",
    item: "list item 3"
  }

Comment: Wouldn't that format be much easier : {title: 'Title1', list: ['list item 1', 'list item 2', 'list item 3''] } ?

Comment: Ok, so the reason why this needs to be differewnt is because in LI there is actually 2 span element
```
<li><span class="opening-day">Monday</span><span class="opening-times"> 12pm - 4pm</span></li>
```
I didn't put this into the intial HTML as I was going to try myself if I knew how to get into the indvidual LI element. But again, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'll give you an answer, but the way you put it is still a bit vague. If my answer is not very useful for your question, comment something in my answer that I will try to help. You could also edit your answer by specifying it better, it would also help

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this with Puppeteer. Just uncomment the `page.evaluate()` function. I just commented it so that you can run the snippet and see the results.

You can't have multiple object entries with keys that are all the same, so a better solution might be to return an array with the `li` values, as the keys do not matter anyway, right?

```js
const result = []

//await page.evaluate(() => {
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div')
  divs.forEach(div => {
    const obj = {
      title: div.querySelector('.title').innerText,
      list: [...div.querySelectorAll('ul li')].map(i => i.innerText)
    }
    result.push(obj)
  })
//})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div id="collection">
  <div class="div">
    <h1 class="title">Title 1</h1>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>list item 1</li>
      <li>list item 2</li>
      <li>list item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <h1 class="title">Title 2</h1>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>list item 1a</li>
      <li>list item 2a</li>
      <li>list item 3a</li>
      <li>list item 4a</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <h1 class="title">Title 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do the following on your puppeteer script, i think it might work:

```js
const values = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const titles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.title')).map(el => el.innerText); // this will get you an array with the titles  
    const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.list')).map(el => Array.from(el.children).map(elm => elm.innerText));

    const endArray = titles.map((el, index) => {
      return {
        title: el,
        list: list[index],
      }
    })

    return endArray;
});
```

You cannot have an object with repeated attributes as you're trying to do. It's a better practice to define your list as an array, since you know your list has a repeated type of data.